# Tumblr jQuery - code not executing (NOT Masonry / Infinite scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, tumblr

So, I was helping a friend develop a theme for her tumblr. As every reasonable web dev would do, I first developed it locally on my harddrive, putting in filler images. On my local copy, everything works fine. When I port it to a tumblr theme, a portion of the jQuery code ceases to function.

I'm using jQuery 2.0.3, and have MixItUp working, and a lightbox-esque function I wrote.

Here's the bit in question:

**jQuery/javascript**

```
        $(window).load(function() {
                $('.mix').on('click', function() {
                    var source = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
                    var image = $('<img src='+source+'>');
                    $('.overlay').children().remove();
                    $('.overlay').append(image);
                    $('.overlay').find('img').load(function() {
                        var overlayWidth = $('.overlay').width();
                        var overlayHeight = $('.overlay').height();
                        var overlayWPadding = overlayWidth - 40;
                        var imageWidth = $('.overlay').find('img').width();
                        var imageHeight = $('.overlay').find('img').height();
                        if (imageWidth > overlayWidth) {
                            var ratio = imageWidth / imageHeight;
                            var adjustedHeight = overlayWPadding / ratio;
                            var marginValue = (overlayHeight - adjustedHeight) / 2;
                            var marginTop = marginValue + "px";
                            $('.overlay').find('img').width(overlayWPadding);
                            $('.overlay').find('img').height(adjustedHeight);
                            $('.overlay').find('img').css('margin', ''+marginTop+' auto');
                        }
                    });
                    $('.overlay').css({'left': '200px', 'display': 'none'}).fadeIn(1000);
                });
                $('.overlay').on('click', function() {
                    $(this).fadeOut(500);
                });
        });
```

The **HTML** it affects:

```
    <div id="Grid">
        <div class="mix">
          <img src="img/02.jpg" />
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
```

The respective tumblr code for it:

```
    <div id="Grid">

    {block:Posts}
    <div class="mix" id="{PostID}">
        {block:Photo}
                <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" />
        {/block:Photo}
    </div>
    {/block:Posts}

</div>
```

The problem is that the function doesn't add the .overlay div when an image is clicked. Like I said, this works fine when I coded it locally, but when I load this into tumblr, it doesn't work. What's wrong and how do I fix it?

I don't think the CSS is the problem, but I'll put up any requested CSS.

**Edit:**

Comment: Any Error in Console? Are you able to show the link?

Comment: @Surjith No errors in console. Link: http://sdpreview.tumblr.com/

Comment: Which  line of The function should add div.overlay?

Comment: I couldn't find a div named `.overlay` in that page.

Comment: You should add div.overlay as html before load script or add a line in jquery script to add div.overlay. You are setting div.overlay but ir does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because there is no div like `<div class="overlay"></div>` in the given Tumblr page.

The lightbox is working fine when I added the below code.

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Sometime it happens. No Worries. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try use createElement() or appendTo() a div.overlay right after declare var image.

Comment: Thanks. I'd upvote this but I haven't got enough reputation yet.

Comment: Sorry I cant code very well cause im on Mobile. But this solution should be better if your div.overlay Will be destroyed after you click on it and you need The div to be added again without reload The page.

Comment: actually, when div.overlay is clicked, it's only hidden, since I used fadeOut(). You make a fair point though.